# The life cycle of the Intent?

Tags: android

Does the Intent have life cycle?
If the Intent has life cycle,what is it like in the life cycle?

Comment: read this for help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Answer (score 6):

Either I'm not really sure what you mean, or you do not fully understand an [intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).

An intent is a message. It is used to start some sort of process, either explicitly by naming the activity, or implicitly. It can have some data to send to the intent.

If you would make a "lifecycle", it would look something like this

- Creation.
- Resolution
- Destruction

It has a lifecycle like most objects, in the sense that it is made, used and destroyed. It does not have a lifecycle like an activity, with calls and methods and all that.

Answer (score 0):

No Intent does not have any Life cycle . They allow to send or receive data from and to other activities or services.Intents are basically message that is passed between components (such as Activities, Services, Broadcast Receivers, and Content Providers).

for more details see the [link](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)