# Whats happen to old intent when new intent received?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

There are 3 activity (A-B-C)

Activity A send an intent to activity B first

Then activity C send another intent to activity B

In Activity B, `getIntent()` will return the newer intent? In other words: is the newer intent overriding the older intent?

Is there a way to keep an intent history?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The life cycle of the Intent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699183/the-life-cycle-of-the-intent)

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar I read that but there was nothing useful for my case

Comment: why it not useful to you?

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar because there was nothing about overriding two incoming intent

Comment: this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5699234/1168654 @Nanne tell that "It has a lifecycle like most objects, in the sense that it is made, used and destroyed. It does not have a lifecycle like an activity, with calls and methods and all that." it means every time you call intent its override previous one.

Comment: Rephrased the question partly to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: if i start *activity B* from *activity A* and then i want to relaunch it from *activity C* with intent's flag >>> `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`<<< i just need in *activity B* override `protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)` and get extra from new intent that received from *activity C*